# Styling images in React Native

Tags: react-native

A part of my react native application currently looks like this:

Where the graph and picture are next to each other. My current code is:

```
<View style={{flexDirection:"row", backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF', borderRadius:10}}>

        <View style={{flex:1, padding:10}}>
          <Card.Cover source={{uri: props.url}}/>
        </View>

        <View style={{flex:1, padding:10}}>
          <BarChartExample></BarChartExample>
        </View>
        
      </View>
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me fix what is wrong in my code to get my image looking like the example image.

Comment: Can you please add your `Card.Cover` component code ?

Comment: You  can use image property resizeMode  to set layout .

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the `resizeMode` props on the  component to `contain`.

More information here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode